# What difference between these two docker IPs?

Tags: docker

I got confused between these two ip addresses :

```
$ docker-machine ls
NAME      ACTIVE   URL          STATE     URL                         SWARM   DOCKER    ERRORS
default   *        virtualbox   Running   tcp://192.168.99.100:2376           v1.10.3
```

and:

```
$ docker inspect aa769fbe3a3a | grep IPAddress | cut -d '"' -f 4

172.17.0.2
```

I looked in the docker doc, but can't find an answer.

Can someone explain to me what the ip 192.168.99.100 is used for ?
And what the other ip 172.17.0.2 used for ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first one is the IP of the Linux host which runs the docker daemon

The second one is the IP of the container aa769fbe3a3a [using the bridge network `eth0` to `docker0`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/dockernetworks/).

Se for instance "[Docker Networking](http://sdnhub.org/tutorials/docker-networking/)" :

[image: http://sdnhub.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/docker0-network.png]

Also "[Concerning Containers' Connections: on Docker Networking](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/concerning-containers-connections-docker-networking)":

> When the Docker service dæmon starts, it configures a virtual bridge, `docker0`, on the host system (Figure below).
>   Docker picks a subnet not in use on the host and assigns a free IP address to the bridge. The first try is 172.17.42.1/16, but that could be different if there are conflicts.
>   **This virtual bridge handles all host-containers communications**.

[image: http://www.linuxjournal.com/files/linuxjournal.com/ufiles/imagecache/large-550px-centered/u1002061/11833f1.png]

> When Docker starts a container, by default, it creates a virtual interface on the host with a unique name, such as `veth220960a`, and an address within the same subnet.
>   **This new interface will be connected to the `eth0` interface on the container itself**.
>   In order to allow connections, iptables rules are added, using a DOCKER-named chain. Network address translation (NAT) is used to forward traffic to external hosts, and the host machine must be set up to forward IP packets.

Comment: Thanks VonC, so if I understood, if I want to curl to see the result of a running container I have to do :  $ curl -i 192.168.99.100:49160

Comment: @user1034127 yes, if you have mapped that container port on docker run (https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#expose-incoming-ports): -p 49160:49160

Comment: what the container IP 172.17.0.2 is used for ? what can I do with it ? thanks.

Comment: @user1034127 you can use it from another container to ping the first container for instance.

Comment: Thanks lot VonC, now I understood.